# How do I get my "Scroll to last row" script to apply to all my sheets in the document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 Sheets in my Google Sheets document. I applied this script

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() == lastRow) {
    sheet.appendRow([""]);
  }
  lastRow = lastRow + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

But it only makes the first sheet do it. Not the other two. I really only need it to do it to the second sheet called "DONE". I tried having that sheet active and applying the script and I tried to edit the script to only apply to that sheet name but I don't think I know how to do it properly.

Comment: Answered several times in several places it looks like. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40360 among many others.